# Kendo UI Basic Grid not working/showing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to test Kendo UI Grid but it doesn't seem to be showing anything when I copy the code in the examples, I already have the files and referenced the url to the files correctly in the header.

copying code from grid example: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index

Thanks

[image]

edit: yes I noticed I get these errors in console

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/Users/SM/Desktop/kendo%20ui/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/Users/SM/Desktop/kendo%20ui/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/Users/SM/Desktop/kendo%20ui/js/kendo.all.min.js

Uncaught ReferenceError: kendo is not defined
```

Comment: Do you get an errors in the console of the browser ?

Comment: yes I do I pasted it in comments, thanks, so I gotta get those files?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing kendo.all.min.js, I don't know why it wasn't included in the package

this is what I have in my header and everything works fine now... I didn't even need dataviz in there

```
<link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.all.min.js">
```

alternatively can get original hosted files here:

```
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js">
```

**edit: Beautiful! ALL WORKING NOW!!! I just viewed the source on the example page http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index
then saved kendo.dataviz.moonlight.min.css and examples.css into my Styles folder
this is what I have in my header now:**

```
<link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo.moonlight.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo.dataviz.moonlight.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="styles/examples.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

And now it looks good with no errors in console! Happy! :]
[image]

Comment: make sure all library are under apache license which is only free